# Google sheets : how to generate a number based on the number of digits

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a formula to generate numbers based on the number of digits. I actually want a 1 followed by a number of zeros.

```
5 -> 100000
2 -> 100
1 -> 10
```

I would like to do it in my Google Sheet cell with native Google sheets functions, not in an App script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
=10^A1
```

Comment: @Steph You can also use `=POWER(10,A1)`